# Perfect numpy implementation for this function

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, loss-function

This seems more of a direct question. I will generalize it a bit at the end.

I am trying to this function in numpy. I have been successful using nested for loops but I can't think of a numpy way to do it.

[image: function to implement]

My way of implementation:

```
bs = 10 # batch_size
nb = 8 # number of bounding boxes
nc = 15 # number of classes

bbox = np.random.random(size=(bs, nb, 4)) # model output bounding boxes

p = np.random.random(size=(bs, nb, nc)) # model output probability
p = softmax(p, axis=-1)

s_rand = np.random.random(size=(nc, nc))
s = (s_rand + s_rand.T)/2 # similarity matrix

pp = np.random.random(size=(bs, nb, nc)) # proposed probability
pp = softmax(pp, axis=-1)

first_term = 0
for b in range(nb):
    for b_1 in range(nb):
        if b_1 == b:
            continue
        for l in range(nc):
            for l_1 in range(nc):
                first_term += (s[l, l_1] * (pp[:, b, l] - pp[:, b_1, l_1])**2)
second_term = 0
for b in range(nb):
    for l in range(nc):
        second_term += (np.linalg.norm(s[l, :], ord=1) * (pp[:, b, l] - p[:, b, l])**2)
second_term *= nb

epsilon = 0.5
output = ((1 - epsilon) * first_term) + (epsilon * second_term)
```

I have tried hard to remove the loops and use `np.tile` and `np.repeat` instead, in order to achieve the task. But can't think of a possible way.

I have tried searching google for finding exercises like such which can help me learn such conversions in numpy but wasn't successful.

Comment: do you have some input and some expected output data?

Comment: Nope, as this is a loss function for one of my model. But I can share the shapes of numpy arrays. Will update the question.

Comment: Just make up some numbers?

Comment: Yep.. It works. Already tested it. So, I just need a better alternative. BTW, updated the question.

Comment: I guess the inner loops can be replaced by a .dot operation (sum of products)

Comment: You code produces an output array, yet you initialize your variables with ints. This does not seem right.

Comment: It produces an array because it outputs a loss value for each batch.

Comment: @Stefan Can you please write that code for a better understanding?

Comment: I don't think my idea works directly because you output a vector (the batches). By the way, your dimensions are not very big, so I suppose the code is not very slow?

Comment: @Stefan the dimensions are not very big as this is an example code. In practice it will be large arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximally optimized code: (removal of first two loops is inspired from L.Iridium's answer)

```
squared_diff = (pp[:, :, None, :, None] - pp[:, None, :, None, :]) ** 2
weighted_diff = s * squared_diff
b_eq_b_1_removed = b.sum(axis=(3,4)) * (1 - np.eye(nb))
first_term = b_eq_b_1_removed.sum(axis=(1,2))

normalized_s = np.linalg.norm(s, ord=1, axis=1)
squared_diff = (pp - p)**2
second_term = nb * (normalized_s * squared_diff).sum(axis=(1,2))

loss = ((1 - epsilon) * first_term) + (epsilon * second_term)
```

Timeit track:
`512 µs ± 13 µs per loop`

Timeit track of code posted in question:
`62.5 ms ± 197 µs per loop`

That's a huge improvement.

Answer (score 1):

`P_hat.shape` is (B,L), `S.shape` is (L,L), `P.shape` is (B,L).

```py
array_before_sum = S[None,:,None,:]*(P_hat[:,:,None,None]- P_hat[None,None,:,:])**2
array_after_sum = array_before_sum.sum(axis=(1,3))
array_sum_again = (array_after_sum*(1-np.ones((B,B)))).sum()
first_term = (1-epsilon)*array_sum_again

second_term = epsilon*(B*np.abs(S).sum(axis=1)[None,:]*(P_hat - P)**2).sum()
```

Comment: Haven't checked this yet, but it seems correct. Will update here after cross checking. But a small question though. How did you do this? I mean, I can't think of such a way. Where did you practice/learn from? Please let me know.. I too want to learn.

Comment: Verified this. Output differs. Hence, not the correct one. Can you please explain your implementation? @L.Iridium

Comment: I just implementation the equation in my way, so I have not check whether the output is same. For me, the  relation between the subscripts in the equation and the index of the numpy array is very important to understand the problem. Being familiar with the broadcast rules is also useful. Besides, the shape of array is useful, too.

Comment: In my view, from the four summation in the first term we know that we convert a four dimension array to a number. So, I use the broadcast rules to add the (B, L,1,1) shape `P_hat` and the (1,1,B',L') shape into a (B,L,B',L') four dimension array and power it's every element, B=B', L=L'. Then, convert the shape of S from (L, L') into (1, L, 1,L') in order to broadcast it into (B,L,B',L'). Then, I first sum the L and L' dimension for there is no constrain for this summation and get a (B,B') array.

Comment: Continuing. I find that under the constrain, b≠b', the summation do not include the element in the diagonal. Therefore, I utilize the identity matrix to solve it. Those are only the process in my brain. Something may be wrong. And FYI.

Comment: Got it.. found the error in your code. Am correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do both with `einsum`

```
first_term = np.einsum('km, ijklm -> i', s, (pp[..., None, None] - pp[:, None, None, ...])**2 )
second_term = np.einsum('k, ijk -> i', np.linalg.norm(s, axis = 1), (pp - p)**2 )
```

Now there's a problem: that `ijklm` tensor in `first_term` is going to get huge if `nb` and `nc` get large.  You should probably distribute it so that you get 3 smaller tensors:

```
first_term =    np.einsum('km, ijk, ijk -> i', s, pp, pp)  +\
                np.einsum('km, ilm, ilm -> i', s, pp, pp)  -\
            2 * np.einsum('km, ijk, ilm -> i', s, pp, pp)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `(a-b)**2 = a**2 + b**2 - 2ab` to allow you to break the problem into three parts that can each be done in one step with the dot product

Comment: I will try your way. But can you please explain how einsum works? Also, how will this give me a speed benefit?

Comment: I tried your way. The output provided by your way differs from the one I get with the code posted in question. I think you are missing the condition `b != b_1`. Can you please crosscheck?

Comment: Just lost all my free time today, so I can't really debug.  Not sure how to implement that inequality either.  I'll leave it up to hopefully inspire one of the other `einsum` masters around here.

Comment: No problem.. Thanks for trying it though.